# SSM Patch manager Patch policy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, patch, aws-ssm, amazon-linux-2

The requirement is to do the patching of existing EC2 instances. So we decided to work with AWS Patch Manager under the Systems Manager.

Issue: We have added `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` Policy Role to all instances. Whenever we try to do on-demand patching ( Patch Now ) it is working without error.

But when we need automatically scheduled patching which can be done by `"Patch Policy"` it gives an error into the installation part of the state manager. Currently, we are having EC2 instances of Amazon Linux2 OS and Ubuntu 16.04 OS. When we tried creating a new instance in a personal account with the same OS Amazon Linux 2, It is giving the same error.

Even tried with `SSMFullaccess` policy.

Sometimes we find this error.

No IMDS credentials were found on the instance.failed to run commands: `exit status 156`

Expecting to get the patch policy done without any fail.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue I guess, my Patch policy was set up using quick-start and so the manual scan&patch was running fine whereas the quick-start association was failing instead.
The catch is that I'm using a custom role on EC2 instances and solved it adding a missing tag on the ec2-role, as suggested on this page..
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/quick-setup-patch-manager.html#patch-policy-instance-profile-service-role

It wasn't obvious at all, hope it helps!

Comment: I added this during the patch policy creation time. Still had issue. But currently solved all of them. I will update soon.